# Java - Searching a 2D array for an array

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

Are there any builtin method or library in Java to search for an array within a 2D array?

**Example:**

```
public static final short[][] roots = new short[][] {
       {0x02, 0x3c, 0x81, 0xcc, 0xe8, 0xe7, 0xc6, 0x4f},
       {0x09, 0x99, 0xbf, 0x90, 0x0b, 0xd5, 0xc2, 0x97},
       ....
};

// Array to find
short[] itemArray = {0x09, 0x99, 0xbf, 0x90, 0x0b, 0xd5, 0xc2, 0x97};
```

What's the best way to check if `itemArray` is available in `roots`?

**Update:** `roots` is a sorted array. Anyway the search could take advantage of `Arrays.binarySearch` ? I suppose `Comparator<short[]>` could help (how to write one)?

Comment: Consider reading this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-arrays-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(roots, itemArray, (arr1, arr2) -> {
    // your compare algorithm goes here.
});
if (index != -1) {
    // get your array with roots[index].
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (short[] arr1 : roots){
   if (Arrays.equals(arr1, itemArray)){ return true;}
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2) is a built in function to compare 1D arrays for equality check.

you can use it.

```
for(short [] arr : roots) {
  if (Arrays.equals(arr1, itemArray)) {
     // arr1 matches the itemArray
     // you can also use a counter variable to return the row number    
  }
}
```